# How to get dynamic fields by using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the expected markup which is created dynamically

```
<textarea data-ng-model="cv.experience[content.title]"></textarea>
<textarea data-ng-model="cv.experience[content.title]"></textarea>
...
```

This is the sample of the **JSON** I want to achieve

```
experience:{

    content:[
        {
            header:String,
            title:String,
            start_date:Date,
            end_date:Date,
            location:String,
            description:String
        },
        {
            header:String,
            title:String,
            start_date:Date,
            end_date:Date,
            location:String,
            description:String
        },
        ....
    ]
}
```

How can i archive above structure using `ng-model`

Comment: Check out my solution and see if that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for this:

This creates a textarea for each object in `cv.experience.content` and then binds `ng-model` to each object's title property. I think this is what you're after, yes?

```
<textarea data-ng-model="content.title" data-ng-repeat="content in cv.experience.content">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks but nature of `ng-model` is two way **data binding** when i want to update data in any `textarea` it appear to all `textarea` that is problem for me, I need when user enter data to any `textarea` not appear to all `textarea` and create object on repeated fields as my **JSON** structure

Comment: @Kassambinary I'm not entirely sure what you mean by that. If you run this code, it will only bind each textarea to a single object's title property. If you are expecting `ng-model` to create and build out JSON for you, that's not what `ng-model` does. I would suggest reading the documentation on it.